# Database level Trigger on table creation to prevent creation of tables without Primary Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to come up with a way to prevent analysts from creating tables without a Primary key. I know how to create a database level trigger, and I know how to query to find whether or not a table has a primary key, but I was hoping that SQL Server has a 'Created' table, much in the same way it has 'inserted'/'updated' tables used in ON INSERT/ON UPDATE triggers.

Hypothetically, if SQL Server did have this 'Created' table, my trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PKViolations
ON DATABASE   
FOR CREATE_TABLE  
AS   

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM Created
           WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID,'TableHasPrimaryKey') = 0)

    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Please include a Primary Key. Transaction has been rolled back.'
        ROLLBACK;
    END
```

**Instructing analysts on importance of primary keys has helped, but tables are still being created without PKs, any insight is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EVENTDATA() to get the ObjectName. Then you can use your query to examine if there is a primary key.

```
SELECT NewTableName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)')
```

You can read more about EVENTDATA here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql

Here is a fully functional example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PKViolations
ON DATABASE   
FOR CREATE_TABLE  
AS   

    declare @NewTableName nvarchar(255)
    SELECT @NewTableName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)')

    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@NewTableName),'TableHasPrimaryKey') = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Please include a Primary Key. Transaction has been rolled back.'
        ROLLBACK;
    END

go
```

Comment: Wow, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: If this works you should consider marking this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. I apologizing for not having done that already -- I am a very new user to stack overflow, still getting the hang of it!